# Logging + Lttng framework logs not available

Tags: python, logging, trace, lttng

I am using `logging` + `lttng` as logging and tracing framework but I am not able to view the logs using `lttng view` it just gives me the path of the logs

I am using the following example

**Python Example**

```
import lttngust
import logging
import time


def example():
    logging.basicConfig()
    logger = logging.getLogger('my-logger')

    while True:
        logger.debug('debug message')
        logger.info('info message')
        logger.warn('warn message')
        logger.error('error message')
        logger.critical('critical message')
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example()
```

Following commands are executed to enable `lttng`

Steps

```
lttng create
lttng enable-event --python my-logger
lttng start
```

Run the Python script:

```
python test.py
```

Stop tracing and inspect the recorded events:

```
lttng stop
lttng view //Not working as expected
```

**On running lttng view**

```
vinay@root:~/lttng-traces/auto-20180917-121542/ust/uid/1003/64-bit/index$ lttng view
Trace directory: /home/vinay/lttng-traces/auto-20180917-121542
```

Comment: What version of Python, LTTng-UST, LTTng-Tools, and Babeltrace are you using? Also, on what distro and version are you trying that?

Comment: I tried using `python` and `python3` both do I need `babeltrace` in this case if yes why and do you have any examples which I can refer to.

Comment: Yes you need Babeltrace. Babeltrace is called by the lttng view command. What version of the software I listed above are you using?

Comment: @fdeslaur can use the above example and try it My versions are as follows `lttng --version
lttng (LTTng Trace Control) 2.10.2 - KeKriek
`

Comment: I tried it. It works fine on my machine. What distro and version are you using? Have you installed lttng-tools using distro packages or built it from source?

Comment: @fdeslaur awesome glad to hear that. could you please share your version of different lttng entities and write an answer to this question with output I will upvote your answer. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I have an idea of the reason you see this problem but I need to know what distro, version and installation method you are using to confirm that it's indeed the problem.

Comment: distro version Ubuntu 18.04 i have used the installation steps given here in the link https://lttng.org/docs/v2.10/#doc-python-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that you are running on lttng-tools 2.10.2.
This version affected by a bug with the Python tracing agent.

The bug makes it impossible to trace python applications when the user is not part of the `tracing` group **and** the lttng session daemon is running as root. This requirement normally only exists for kernel tracing. You are encountering this bug because systemd launches a root lttng session daemon at startup.

You can easily test if it's indeed this bug by logging in as root and killing the root lttng session daemon and running a session daemon as your own non-root user like this:

As root:

```
pkill lttng-sessiond
```

As your non-root user:

```
lttng-sessiond -d
lttng create
lttng enable-event --python my-logger
lttng start
python test.py
...
<ctrl + c>
lttng stop
lttng view
```

If you get events now then your are affected by the bug. 
This bug has been fixed in the 2.10 branch and will make it to the Ubuntu packages.

Until the package gets updated, you can add yourself to the `tracing` group or prevent systemd from launch a root lttng session daemon on startup.

Comment: No luck same behavior even after pkill of lttng-sessiond

Comment: Can you confirm that the root lttng-sessiond process is indeed killed by the pkill command? You can check that using `ps aux | grep lttng-sessiond`.

Comment: Actually that was not the bug I cleaned up everything a created a fresh session and it worked really well :)